# Are there universities who take your mathoverflow score seriously

Tags: soft-question

When being considered for a position at a university as a post doc or phd or professor, does your math overflow account mean anything.  Are there any universities that take this seriously when looking at your application?

Comment: It seems unlikely, but nothing surprises me any more ...

Comment: This is probably a better fit for meta.mathoverflow. I recall a comment to some question there indicating that some math department chairs weight mathoverflow participation negatively.

Comment: @PaulSiegel: Negatively? Really?

Comment: @Jamai-Con Presumably on the basis that it was a waste of time.

Comment: I see..........

Comment: On the plus side, Timothy Gowers has told of a student he knew only from the student's MO postings, who asked Gowers to write him a letter of recommendation based on their MO interactions – which Gowers was very happy to do.

Comment: Some years ago I devoted a paragraph of a letter of recommendation for graduate school to an undergraduate's contributions to MathOverflow. At the time this undergraduate had the fifth highest ranking of any user! I don't know whether this discussion was at all helpful.

Comment: Both of those students are me, incidentally.

Comment: Now posted on meta: [Are there universities who take your MathOverflow score seriously](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/3407).